# ahk how to select a variable after looping

Tags: loops, variables, autohotkey

I am preety much stuck with -I guess- a really simple problem.
I collected map coordinates via pointerscanning. Part of the code looks like this:

```
loop 8 {

gate1%A_Index%base := ReadMemory1(mark%A_Index%base + 0x38,v)

addressgate1%A_Index%x := gate1%A_Index%base + 0x4   

gate1%A_Index%x := HexToFloat(ReadMemory1(addressgate1%A_Index%x,v))

}
```

gate11x, gate12x, gate13x,...,gate18x i will have. This variables can hold either 0 or any number.

Like: 0,0,-132,0,0,-500,0,0 .

Which type of loop and expression should I use if I only want to have the non-zero variables? I would need a result:

```
GATENO1x := (variable that holds -132)      
GATENO2x := (variable that holds -500)
```

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
gate1_Index := ""   ; empty variable

loop 8 {
gate1%A_Index%base := ReadMemory1(mark%A_Index%base + 0x38,v)
addressgate1%A_Index%x := gate1%A_Index%base + 0x4   
gate1%A_Index%x := HexToFloat(ReadMemory1(addressgate1%A_Index%x,v))
If gate1%A_Index%x not in 0
    gate1_Index .=  gate1%A_Index%x . "," ; concatenate the outputs by adding a comma to each one
}
gate1_Index := SubStr(gate1_Index, 1, -1) ; remove the last comma from this variable
Loop, parse, gate1_Index, `,
    MsgBox, GATENO%A_Index%x = %A_LoopField%
```

Comment: Thx, you helped a lot ;)